# Recv returning zero incorrectly

Tags: c++, networking, recv

I have an interesting problem,

- I send bytes of data to my server, from my client, and the recv() function always returns zero.
- I have verified that the function is indeed getting the data and placing it into the char array correctly. It just returns zero regardless of the number of bytes received.
- I have verified that the client is still properly connected after recv() returns a zero, and can still send and receive data to and from the server.

This creates a problem for me. I need to total up the chars coming in to determine when a message is completed. Can someone explain what could cause the recv() command to behave in this manner?

```
// clean the buffer of any previous received data
// by resetting all bytes to zero
ReadBufferClear();

// try to read some data, using the read buffer
if(this->Return_Value = recv(this->Socket_Filedescriptor,            
                    this->ReadBuffer_Data,
                    this->ReadBuffer_Size,
                    0) == -1)
{
    // returned -1, notify the server it needs
    // to remove this connections FD, and 
    // close this connection class entry;
    return -1;
}    

// print return value
fprintf(stdout,"%i\n",this->Return_Value);

// print out the bytes
for(int curPos  =0; curPos<this->ReadBuffer_Size; curPos++)
    fprintf(stdout,"%i\n",this->ReadBuffer_Data[curPos]);
```

output looks like this:

0
0
1
-1
-1
-1
-2
-1
-1
0
0

Comment: Can you show code, preferably a runnable program, that demonstrates this please?

Comment: Either this is a major bug in your platform or some subtle error in your code.

Comment: Code please! - without it, it is very hard to tell.

Comment: What makes you think it's incorrect? Where's the sending code? Zero indicates that the connection was closed by the peer. There's no evidence here that that hasn't happened. NB Printing the contents of a buffer beyond the number of bytes that were actually received is futile.

Comment: Assuming you talk about POSIX recv() I somewhat doubt that its behaviour is so blatantly buggy...

Comment: @EJP If you had read the top lines, you would note that the connection was still open, active and usable. Which is not in line with the behaviour described by the manual pages.

Comment: @sharptooth My client is written in java, and doesn't have this problem. Its recv() calls return the byte count properly. So I am going to assume its not an OS level issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a precedence problem. The line should be of the form

```
if ((this->ReturnValue = recv(..).)) == -1)
```

At present you're comparing the result of recv() with -1 and storing the Boolean result of that comparison into ReturnValue.

So recv() isn't returning zero at all.